# header crashing app with error TypeError: undefined not an object (evaluating 'theme.label')

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

When trying to navigate through views the app crashes. And the Error log has not enough information about the causes. I already tried to switch between node versions or react-navigation and nothing seems to work, the project also implements react-native-paper for theming. 
This, with the following configs in the navigation:

```
const SomeView = createStackNavigator({
  SomeView:{
    screen: SomeViewScreen
  },
  AnotherView:{
    screen: AnotherViewScreen
  }
},
{
  mode: 'card', 
  // headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {  
    header: null,
 }
}
);

this works but is not rendering any header


const SomeView = createStackNavigator({
  SomeView:{
    screen: SomeViewScreen
  },
  AnotherView:{
    screen: AnotherViewScreen
  }
},
{
  mode: 'card', 
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {  
    header: null,
 }
}
);
```

The package.json has the following config:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "help": "^3.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.9.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.10",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^1.0.0"
  },
```

The Error log:

[Screenshot of the device with the Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUm9P.png)

Comment: Could you add the code of `Header.txt` on line `223` because that is where the error occurred. This will help find the issue.

Comment: Apparently it was a dismatch in the expo's react-native version. But any way the problem origins on the HeaderTitle.tsx on the react-navigation-stack folder in the node_modules due to the theme applied from react-native-paper
this is the code from HeaderTitle:
return (
      <Animated.Text
        numberOfLines={1}
        {...rest}
        style={[styles.title, { color: theme.label }, style]}
        accessibilityTraits="header"
      />
    );

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, but just changing the react-native version does not have any effect. What exactly did you do to solve the problem? Did you really just replace the ´react-native´ entry in ´package.json´? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was a dismatch in the expo's react-native version. It works if you switch to

```
"react-native": "^0.57.1"
```

This is due to a theme dismatch applied from react-native-paper and expo's react native version